# Mapreduce Program(Java) using Distributed Cache

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Hi I am new to Hadoop Mapreduce programming. Actually I have a requirement like below:

### larger file i.e the input file input.txt

```
101 Vince 12000

102 James 33

103 Tony 32

104 John 25

105 Nataliya 19

106 Anna 20

107 Harold 29
```

### And this is the smaller file lookupfile.txt

```
101 Vince 12000

102 James 10000

103 Tony 20000

104 John 25000

105 Nataliya 15000
```

Now what we want is to get those results which have common Id Number. So, in order to achieve this use smaller file as look up file and larger file as input file. The complete java code and explanation of each component is given below:

### This is the result we will get after running the above code.

```
102     James   33      10000

103     Tony    32      20000

104     John    25      25000

105     Nataliya        19      15000
```

### Code:

```
public class Join extends Configured implements Tool 
{

public static class JoinMapper extends Mapper
{
   Path[] cachefiles = new Path[0]; //To store the path of lookup files
   List exEmployees = new ArrayList();//To store the data of lookup files

  /********************Setup Method******************************************/
  @Override
  public void setup(Context context) 

   {
    Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();

   try 
   {

  cachefiles = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(conf);
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(cachefiles[0].toString())); 

      String line;

 while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) 
  {
   exEmployees.add(line);  //Data of lookup files get stored in list object
  }

  }
 catch (IOException e) 
 {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }

   } 


    /************************setup method ends***********************************************/

   /********************Map Method******************************************/

     public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {


   String[] line = value.toString().split("\t");


   for (String e : exEmployees)  
     {

      String[] listLine = e.toString().split("\t");

        if(line[0].equals(listLine[0]))

      {
     context.write(new Text(line[0]), new Text(line[1]+"\t"+line[2]+"\t"+listLine[2]));
      }

    }


   }    //map method ends
 /***********************************************************************/


}

   /********************run Method******************************************/

    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {

  Configuration conf = new Configuration();
  Job job = new Job(conf, "aggprog");
  job.setJarByClass(Join.class);
  DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new Path(args[0]).toUri(), job.getConfiguration());

  FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args [1]));
  FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args [2]));
  job.setMapperClass(JoinMapper.class);
  job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
  job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
  return (job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
}

 public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception 
 {
 int ecode = ToolRunner.run(new Join(), args);
   System.exit(ecode);
 }
 }
```

### Execution Command :

### case1:

```
hadoop jar '/home/cloudera/Desktop/DistributedCache.jar' Join My_Job/MultiInput_1/Input/input.txt My_Job/MultiInput_1/Input/smallerinput.txt My_Job/MultiInput_1/My_Output
```

### case2:

```
hadoop jar '/home/cloudera/Desktop/DistributedCache.jar' Join My_Job/MultiInput_1/Input/input.txt My_Job/MultiInput_1/Input/smallerinput.txt My_Job/MultiInput_1/My_Output
```

I have tried above two commands, but it is not working. I don't Know what the problem is and also where the problem is. I am unable to execute the above code.

### finally i tried below code it worked

```
hadoop jar '/home/cloudera/Desktop/DistributedCache.jar' Join hdfs/Input/smallerfile.txt hdfs/Input/input.txt My_Job/MultiInput_1/MyOutput
```

I found my mistake. I was checking the large file with the small file. But, when I tried the reverse way it worked for me, but the output was not as expected.

Expected output is:

```
101 Vince 12000

102 James 33 10000

103 Tony 32 20000

104 John 25 25000

105 Nataliya 19 15000

106 Anna 20

107 Harold 29
```

But my output is:

```
101 Vince 12000

102 James 33 10000

103 Tony 32 20000

104 John 25 25000

105 Nataliya 19 15000

106 Anna 20

107 Harold 29
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Those files are on HDFS, right?  That's where they need to be for this code to work.  A forward slash would help, too.

Comment: Hi chris... Do i need to put the jor file on HDFS too.. and  try for it..

Answer (score 0):

Yes user3475485. Your files should be put in hdfs for this code to run or because your are using Genericoptionsparse you can use this format

hadoop jar jarname.jar drivername -files file1,file2 should work for you.

Comment: Can you please share more details about error ? what error does it throws ?

Comment: It works perfectly fine only the output was not as expected... if u can see my post i have explained clearly abt expected output and wat i achieved